# React-Native Switch in ListItem is alwaays unchecked

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

I have a list of objects which I want to show in a FlatList. The list items should also have a switch to select or deselect the entry. But everytime I click the switch, the state stays unchecked. I don't know if this is a bug of the ListItem component or in my code. The onValueChange event is triggered correctly but then it seems that the FlatList is not rerendered after changing the state or the dataset is not updated...

Here are my classes:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this._name = '';
    this._selected = false;
  }

  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }

  setName(value) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  isSelected() {
    return this._selected;
  }

  setSelected(value) {
    this._selected = value;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let p1 = new Person();
    p1.setName('Superman');
    let p2 = new Person();
    p2.setName('Batman');
    let list = [ p1, p2 ];
    this.state = { persons: list };
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
    <ListItem
      title={item.getName()}
      switch={{
        value: item.isSelected(),
        onValueChange: (value) => {
          let list = this.state.persons;
          list[index].setSelected(value);
          this.setState({ persons: list });
        },
      }}
    />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.persons}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try different variable names. And for the data to be updated, it must be refreshing. Create a refreshing structure.  `<FlatList
            style={styles.listContainer}
            onRefresh={this.refreshData}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            data={this.state.data}
          />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, only the `extraData` property of the FlatList component is missing.

Checkout the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist):

> By passing `extraData={this.state}` to FlatList we make sure FlatList
>   itself will re-render when the `state.selected` changes. Without setting
>   this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items
>   because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not
>   show any changes.

In your case, it has to be:

```
<FlatList
     data={this.state.persons}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
     extraData={this.state}
/>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://snack.expo.io/BkU4vZwqV).